# Migrate from Jboss 5.1 to jetty

Tags: jetty, jboss5.x

Currently My web Application is running on jboss 5.1 and we need to migrate it to jetty server..i am looking for a complete detail and steps to do the process...Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there exists a step by step document along the lines you are looking for.  It largely depends on your web application how simple or hard the migration would be.  If you are using EJB's for instance then you would have to also factor in the openejb integration we have some support for, if it is a straight war file then it is likely much easier.  There are professional services from the jetty developers available to help if you like, you can google Webtide for that.  I would recommend going straight to Jetty 9.1 though, the new distribution layout makes things a fair amount easier to separate things out.

Current documentation is here though: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/